# Generating dataframe with argument as column name & Selecting column based on argument

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, arguments, parameter-passing

I am having a couple of challenges with arguments. Is someone able to assist me? Thanks a lot!

```
argument_a <- “GID”
```

1. how do I create an empty dataframe with a column name defined by the argument. This example below will obviously not work, but may help you understand what I’m trying to achieve. I wish the column name of df to be “GID”:

```
df <- data.frame( argument_a = character())
```

2. How do I select column values based argument. This example below will obviously not work, but may help you understand what I’m trying to achieve. I wish to loop through GID_a, GID_b and GID_c

```
df <- data.frame(GID =  c('GID_a','GID_b','GID_c'))

for (i in list(unique(df$argument_a))){}
```

Comment: Creating an empty dataframe is very rarely (never) helpful. Why do you want to do this? There could be better ways to achieve your overall goal but we would need more context for this. A complete and reproducible example along with expected output would be helpful to understand what you want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part of your question, I'd go with some non-standard evaluation. Basically, you want to evaluate argument_a and then create the dataframe (so that the column doesn't get the name of the variable, like argument_a). I couldn't get this to work with base data.frame, but it's fine with tibble:

```
library(rlang)
library(tibble)

argument_a <- "GID"

df <- tibble(!!argument_a := character())
```

The !! ("bang-bang") here evaluates argument_a, so that the column is named with the value of argument_a ("GID"). You need this operator after it :=, called the Walrus operator, because you are evaluating on the left hand side of an assignment.

For part 2 I'd just use brackets to index instead of $.

```
df <- data.frame(GID = c('GID_a','GID_b','GID_c'))

for (i in list(unique(df[[argument_a]]))){

     print(i)
 }
```

There are really useful overviews of these concepts in the [Advanced R metaprogramming section](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/metaprogramming.html).